# Is it possible to join tables based on different columns, dependent on if a value is present?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to build row level security on a dashboard.
I have 2 helper tables described below - one that shows user access and one that shows branches

### User Access

| User | Branch | Region | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User A | MEL | All | All |
| User A | All | SP | All |
| User B | All | IP | All |
| User B | All | SP | All |
| User C | All | All | NZ |

### Branch

| Branch | Region | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MEL | SP | AU |
| SYD | SP | AU |
| AKL | SP | NZ |
| HAN | IP | VN |
| MNL | IP | PH |

The RLS would take into consideration any of the columns (Branch, Region, Country) and filter the fact table based on the associated branch. eg:

| User | Branch |
| --- | --- |
| User A | MEL |
| User A | SYD |
| User A | AKL |
| User B | HAN |
| User B | MNL |
| User B | AKL |
| User B | MEL |
| User B | SYD |
| User C | AKL |

I have tried joining the tables, but as there are three possible joins, I could not get this to work, let alone show incorrect results.

I also tried creating another table with the following DAX, but the results were not correct:

```
RLS = 
    COUNTROWS(
        GENERATE(
            'User Access',
            FILTER(
                'Branch',
                'User Access'[BRANCH] = 'Branch'[BRANCH] ||
                'User Access'[COUNTRY] = 'Branch'[COUNTRY] ||
                'User Access'[REGION] = 'Branch'[REGION]
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hello @Zabman. Your RLS Code does not return a table as you wrote because of "COUNTROWS" function. It returns a scalar value. If you want it to return a table, just omit the countrows. Stay safe :)

Comment: @OzanSen Ideally I would like to do it without a table - best case I would have some DAX in the RLS assessing the Branch table where rowcount >0. I feel like I am almost there as I can successfully get the branch count done when the dax is appended to the User Access Table, but when I put it against the Branch Table, no results are showing up

Comment: Hi @Zabman I understand. Could you please add your model as a screenshot so that lots of people react faster to your problem. I need to see your fact table.

Comment: I also recommend you to check this Microsoft link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/rls-guidance. There is section named "Troubleshoot RLS" when you scrolled down.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
//user table, assumes existence of branch table
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"User", type text}, {"Branch", type text}, {"Region", type text}, {"Country", type text}}),
Buffer=Table.Buffer(branch),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","data",(i)=>Table.SelectRows(Buffer, each 
    i[Branch]="All" and     i[Region]="All" and     i[Country]="All"        or
    i[Branch]="All" and     i[Region]="All" and     i[Country]=[Country]    or
    i[Branch]="All" and     i[Region]=[Region] and  i[Country]="All"        or
    i[Branch]=[Branch] and  i[Region]="All" and     i[Country]="All"        or
    i[Branch]="All" and     i[Region]=[Region] and  i[Country]=[Country]    or
    i[Branch]=[Branch] and  i[Region]="All" and     i[Country]=[Country]    or
    i[Branch]=[Branch] and  i[Region]=[Region] and  i[Country]="All"        or
    i[Branch]=[Branch] and  i[Region]=[Region] and  i[Country]=[Country]    
) [Branch]),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "data"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded data",{"Branch", "Region", "Country"}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns")
in  #"Removed Duplicates"
```

[image]